# Cannot construct instance of (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value

Tags: java, spring, redis, jackson, jackson-databind

I am having issues with my object mapper deseralizing a string that was cached within Redis into an object.

We are caching the object via @Cacheable into redis which then makes the value into

```
"{\"@class\":\"org.BusinessPartyBasicResponse\",\"OutputParameters\":{\"@class\":\"org.BusinessPartyBasicResponse$OutputParameters\",\"X_PARTY_DATA_TABLE\":{\"@class\":\"org.BusinessPartyBasicResponse$OutputParameters$PartyDataTable\",\"X_PARTY_DATA_TABLE_ITEM\":[\"java.util.ArrayList\",[{\"@class\":\"org.BusinessPartyBasicResponse$OutputParameters$PartyDataTable$PartyDataTableItem\",\"TYPECODE\":\"AC\",\"ENTERPRISEID\":\"C4C089BBDD857CDCE0531A1E970A0733\",\"NAME\":\"TEST_NAME CENTER\",\"DOINGBUSINESSASNAME\":null,\"IDENTIFIER\":\"1234\",\"ION\":null,\"COUNTRYCODE\":\"US\",\"STATUS\":\"A\",\"SUPPLIEDSOURCES\":\" \",\"CONTRACT_STATUS\":null,\"OFAC\":null},null]]},\"X_BP_COUNT\":1,\"X_RETURN_STATUS\":\"S\"}}"
```

We are currently using a custom serializer which extends GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer

I can not change any of the field names

However when I try to map it back to BasicPartyBasicResponse as such

```
 public BusinessPartyBasicResponse findByType(BpType bpType) {
        log.info("Find BPs with type=[{}]", bpType);
        Set<String> allBp = ops.keys("common:businessPartyBasic::*");
        BusinessPartyBasicResponse response = new BusinessPartyBasicResponse();
        String bpJson = null;
        for (String bp : allBp) {
            bpJson = ops.opsForValue().get(bp);
            if (bpJson.contains("\"TYPECODE\":\"" + bpType.name().toUpperCase() + "\"")) {
                log.info("bpJson {}", bpJson);
                BusinessPartyBasicResponse basicResponse = null;
                try {
                    basicResponse = mapper.readValue(bpJson, BusinessPartyBasicResponse.class);
                    response.getOutputParameters().setResultsCount(
                            response.getOutputParameters().getResultsCount()
                                    + basicResponse.getOutputParameters().getResultsCount());
                    response.getPartyDataTableItem().addAll(basicResponse.getPartyDataTableItem());
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    log.info("error processing json: {}" ,e);
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        return response;
    }
```

it returns

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `org.BusinessPartyBasicResponse$OutputParameters$PartyDataTable$PartyDataTableItem` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('java.util.ArrayList')
 ...
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1728)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1353)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.StdDeserializer._deserializeFromString(StdDeserializer.java:311)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromString(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1495)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:197)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:187)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:355)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:244)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.deserialize(CollectionDeserializer.java:28)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:129)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.vanillaDeserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:314)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:177)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DefaultDeserializationContext.readRootValue(DefaultDeserializationContext.java:323)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4674)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3629)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3597)
```

As mentioned I can not change the json field names but here is the object
We are getting the object initially from a separate service, thus we cant change the @JsonProperty() names, ive tried changing the variable names so the getter and setter would match the json property field name more properly

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class BusinessPartyBasicResponse {

    public static final String RETURN_STATUS = "S";

    @JsonProperty("OutputParameters")
    private OutputParameters outputParameters = new OutputParameters();

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
    public static class OutputParameters {

        @JsonProperty("X_PARTY_DATA_TABLE")
        private PartyDataTable partyDataTable = new PartyDataTable();

        @JsonProperty("X_BP_COUNT")
        private Integer resultsCount;

        @JsonProperty("X_RETURN_STATUS")
        private String returnStatus;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
        public static class PartyDataTable {

            @JsonProperty("X_PARTY_DATA_TABLE_ITEM")
            private List<PartyDataTableItem> partyDataTableItem = new ArrayList<>();

            @Getter
            @Setter
            @JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
            public static class PartyDataTableItem {

                @JsonProperty("TYPECODE")
                private String bpTypeCode;

                @JsonProperty("ENTERPRISEID")
                private String bpGuid;

                @JsonProperty("NAME")
                private String name;

                @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonNilToStringDeserializer.class)
                @JsonProperty("DOINGBUSINESSASNAME")
                private String doingBusinessAsName;

                @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonNilToStringDeserializer.class)
                @JsonProperty("IDENTIFIER")
                private String identifier;

                @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonNilToStringDeserializer.class)
                @JsonProperty("ION")
                private String ion;

                @JsonProperty("COUNTRYCODE")
                private String country;

                @JsonProperty("STATUS")
                private String status;

                @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonNilToStringDeserializer.class)
                @JsonProperty("SUPPLIEDSOURCES")
                private String suppliedSource;

                @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonNilToStringDeserializer.class)
                @JsonProperty("CONTRACT_STATUS")
                private String contractStatus;

                @JsonDeserialize(using = JsonNilToStringDeserializer.class)
                @JsonProperty("OFAC")
                private String restrictionType;

                @JsonIgnore
                public boolean isRestricted() {
                    return this.restrictionType != null;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with using the object mapper.
With the custom redis serializer which uses a specific serializer (genericjackson2redis)I believed it was using a generic object mapper to deserialize. But that was incorrect so I autowired the custom serializer and used the provided deserialize function and it worked.